# Complement of contractible locally Euclidean subspace

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a connected closed topological manifold. Let $S\subset X$ be a contractible locally Euclidean subspace. Is $X\setminus S$ connected?

Comment: This question is more suitable for math stack exchange. How many contractible compact manifolds do you know?

Comment: @MoisheKohan what do contractible compact manifolds have to do with the question?

Comment: A remark: I don't think it will always be *path* connected. If $X$ is the torus, we can find, for a given meridian $\ell$, a curve $C$ that loops around the torus an infinite amount of times, converging to $\ell$ (in $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb S^1$, take $\ell=\lbrace x=0 \rbrace$ and $C=\lbrace (t,\exp(i/t)),t\leq\varepsilon \rbrace$). Take two such curves $C_1$ and $C_2$, and take $S=C_1\cup C_2$. You can even have $S$ connected. I think in this example $X\setminus S$ is connected, though.

Comment: Are you interested in partial results? It is not too complicated to show that $X\setminus S$ is connected when $S$ is of codimension at least 2 (in which case $S$ connected is enough, instead of contractible). I think I can also show that if the connectedness of $X\setminus S$ holds for all $S$ of codimension 0 ($S$ is a contractible open set), then it is true for arbitrary contractible $S'$, regardless of the codimension.